# The map g(x)=3x+2 and h=sgn(x) on a topological space.

Tags: general-topology

> Question:
>   Define $g,h: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
>   by $g\left ( x \right )=3x+2$
>   and
>   $h\left ( x \right )=sgn\left ( x \right )$.
>   Prove that g is continuous and h is not, as maps of topological space.
>
> Definition: Continuous function on a topological space
>
> Let f be a function between two topological space $\left ( X,\tau \right )$ and $\left ( Y,U \right )$.
>   f is continuous between the two topological space IFF the pre-image of every element in the topology on U is in $\tau$.

I'm having a bit of problem starting this question. 
Any hint or help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $\operatorname{sgn}(0)$?

Comment: Hint: Consider the preimage of the open interval $(1/2, 3/2)$ for the function $h$, i.e. look at $h^{-1}((1/2, 3/2))$. Remember to assume $\operatorname{sgn}(0) = 1$.

Comment: @JackyChong Isn't the signum function at x=0, 0?

Comment: I can never remember the actual value, but nevertheless the method is exactly the same.

Comment: Why do we take the preimage on the open interval you stated?@JackyChong

Comment: If $\operatorname{sgn}(0)=0$, take the preimage of $(-1/2,2)$ instead.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro As we're aware, the signum function...has no inverse..

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Just to give it a try, we get {-1,0,1} which are not open interval so not open sets. Hence they cannot belong to any topology.

Comment: @Mathematicing What? The preimage of $(-1/2,2)$ under $h$ is $[0,\infty)$, which is not open in the **usual** topology. It could be open in some other topology, but that's not what's being considered in the problem.